# Unable to display custom object records in lightning app page

Tags: apex, lightning

I am new to salesforce development and trying to learn salesforce lightning by developing a property project. I had created lightning app page but not able to display custom object records(Property object) in lightning page.The following is the code. I hope you can help.

**PropertyDetails.apxc**

```
public with sharing class PropertyDetails {
public PropertyDetails() {

}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static list`<Property__C>`getLatestProperty(){

list`<Property__C>` allPropertyList = new list`<Property__C>`();

allPropertyList = [SELECT Id,Additional_Room__c,Available_Form__c,Carpet_area_sqft__c,Covered_area_sqft__c,Electricity_Status__c,Facing__c,
Floor__c,For_Bachellor__c,For_Family__c,Furnishing_Available__c,Furnished_Type__c,Geo_Map__c,Landmark__c,Location__c,Area__c,street__c,
State__c,country__c,Maintainance_Charge__c,No_of_Balcony__c,No_Of_Bath_Room__c,No_Of_Bed_Room__c,Property_Description__c,Property_Main_Image__c,
Property_Owner__c,Property_Video_URL__c,Name,Rent__c,Security_Deposit__c,Status__c,Verified__c,Water_Availability__c
FROM Property__c
LIMIT 50
];

return allPropertyList;
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static list`<Property__C>` getSearchedProperty(string location,string bedroom,string bathroom,string maxbudget){

 list`<Property__C>` allPropertyList = new list`<Property__C>`();

 string propertyQuery = 'SELECT Id,Additional_Room__c,Available_Form__c,Carpet_area_sqft__c,Covered_area_sqft__c,Electricity_Status__c,';

 propertyQuery = propertyQuery+'Facing__c,Floor__c,For_Bachellor__c,For_Family__c,Furnished_Type__c,Furnishing_Available__c,Geo_Map__c,';

 propertyQuery = propertyQuery +'Landmark__c, Area__c,street__c,State__c,country__c,Location__c,Maintainance_Charge__c,No_of_Balcony__c,No_Of_Bath_Room__c,No_Of_Bed_Room__c,';

 propertyQuery = propertyQuery +' Property_Description__c,Property_Main_Image__c,Property_Video_URL__c,Name,Rent__c,Security_Deposit__c,Status__c,Verified__c,Water_Availability__c';

 propertyQuery = propertyQuery +' FROM Property__c ';

 string whereClause = 'WHERE Rent__c!=NULL';

      system.debug('****location'+location);

  if(string.isNotBlank(location)){

//string locationSearch = +location+'%';

      if(location !='ALL'){

            whereClause = whereClause+' AND Area__c = :location';

         }

       }

     system.debug('****bedroom'+bedroom);

integer bedroomcount;

  if(string.isNotBlank(bedroom)){

        if(bedroom !='ALL'){

           bedroomcount= integer.valueOf(bedroom);

      system.debug('****bedroomcount'+bedroomcount);

         whereClause = whereClause+' AND No_Of_Bed_Room__c=:bedroomcount';

        }

      }

     system.debug('****bathroom'+bathroom);

    integer bathroomcount;

     if(string.isNotBlank(bathroom)){

         if(bathroom !='ALL'){

           bathroomcount= integer.valueOf(bathroom);

           whereClause = whereClause+' AND No_Of_Bath_Room__c=:bathroomcount';

         }

       }

       system.debug('****maxbudget'+bathroom);

      double maxBudgetValue;

       if(string.isNotBlank(maxbudget)){

        maxBudgetValue = double.valueOf(maxbudget) ;

        whereClause = whereClause+' AND Rent__c<=:maxBudgetValue';

        }

       propertyQuery = propertyQuery +' '+whereClause;

        system.debug('propertyQuery'+propertyQuery);

      allPropertyList = Database.query(propertyQuery);

        system.debug('allPropertyList'+allPropertyList);

        return allPropertyList;

   }

 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static Property__c getDetails(string propId){

         system.debug('getDetails propId'+propId);

      Property__c prop = [SELECT Id,Additional_Room__c,Available_Form__c,Carpet_area_sqft__c,Covered_area_sqft__c,Electricity_Status__c,Facing__c,Floor__c,
      For_Bachellor__c,For_Family__c,Furnishing_Available__c,Furnished_Type__c,Geo_Map__c,Landmark__c,Location__c,State__c,country__c,street__c,
      Area__c,Maintainance_Charge__c,No_of_Balcony__c,No_Of_Bath_Room__c,No_Of_Bed_Room__c,Property_Description__c,Property_Main_Image__c,
      Property_Owner__c,Property_Video_URL__c,Name,Rent__c,Security_Deposit__c,Status__c,Verified__c,Water_Availability__c

      FROM Property__c

      WHERE Id =: propId

      LIMIT 1

      ];

        system.debug('getDetails prop'+prop);

   return prop;

   }

}
```

**ctrif_MyPropertyResult.cmp**

```xml
<aura:component controller="PropertyDetails" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >`

    <aura:attribute name="propertyList" type="Property__c[]"></aura:attribute>`

    <aura:attribute name="propertiesFound" type="boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAllProperty}"/>
       <aura:if isTrue="{!v.propertiesFound}">

        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">

          <aura:iteration items="{!v.propertyList}" var="prop">

                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">

                    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">

                        <div class="slds-box" style="width:100%;background-color:white;">

<lightning:layout>

                            <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">

                                <lightning:formattedRichText value="{!prop.Property_Main_Image__c}"></lightning:formattedRichText>

                                </lightning:layoutItem>

                                <lightning:layoutItem size="8" padding="around-small">

                                    <lightning:card title="{!prop.Furnished_Type__c}">

                                        <lightning:layoutItem size="12">

                                        <p style="color:red;">INR:{!prop.Rent__c}</p>

                                        </lightning:layoutItem>

                                        <lightning:layoutItem size="12">

                                        <p >{!prop.No_Of_Bed_Room__c} BHK house for Rent {!prop.Coverd_area_sqft__c} sqft.</p>

                                        </lightning:layoutItem>

                                        <lightning:layoutItem size="12">

                                        <p >{!prop.Area__c}</p>

                                        </lightning:layoutItem>

                                        <lightning:layoutItem size="12">

                                        <p >{!prop.No_Of_Bed_Room__c} Room {!prop.No_Of_Bath_Room__c} Bathroom {!prop.Furnished_Type__c}</p>

                                        </lightning:layoutItem>



                                    </lightning:card>

                                </lightning:layoutItem>



                            </lightning:layout>                           

                        </div>

                    </lightning:layout>

                </lightning:layoutItem>

            </aura:iteration>



        </lightning:layout>

   <aura:set attribute="else">
            <span>Properties are not listed as per your selection. Please stay tune to future listing.</span>
       </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**ctrif_MyPropertyResultController.js**

```
({

    fetchAllProperty: function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.fetchAllProperty(component, event, helper);

    }

})
```

**ctrif_MyPropertyResultHelper.js**

```
({

    fetchAllProperty : function(component, event, helper)  {

        var action = component.get('c.getLatestProperty');

        action.setCallback(this,function(response){

          var responseValues = response.getReturnValue();

            component.set('v.propertyList',responseValues);

            component.set('v.propertiesFound',true);

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }

})
```

Comment: are you not getting record's or are you getting some error or something else?

Comment: Yes not getting the record's. No  I did not get any error in the code.

Comment: do you have right permission on object to view records?

Comment: Can you please guide me. I tried but I am not getting it.

Comment: what are you seeing on screen "Properties are not listed as per your selection. Please stay tune to future listing."  or just no records

Comment: Yes I am getting "Properties are not listed as per your selection. Please stay tune to future listing."